# Jmeter load testing using single machine

Tags: performance, load, jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

If I test any website and put load on it using jmeter , where actually it puts load?? on my CPU? or on server?

I mean to do load/stress testing of website using single machine give us actual strength/capacity of site? OR for that I need to configure jmeter on server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It puts load on server which you are targeting or which is under load test.**

Using no. of load generators depends on load your server can take. Suppose your server can take 10000 users/transactions then that amount of load is not possible to generate on single load generator with average resources. (core 2 duo cpu, 2-4 gb ram etc.)

Generally average machine/load generator can generate 500-1000 virtual users load. This will hit max. capacity of client without any other applications on it.

**Here question is how do you know 10000 is capacity of my server?**

Answer is you should have an rough idea in advance of your server. some sample test runs and mathematical calculations using **Little's Law** you can find out theoretical limit of your server (which is generally higher than practical limit)

Based on those calculations, setup no. of load generators and perform load testing of server in steps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It really clear my all and big doubts. Have last question that if I install jmeter on server machine then can I test 1000+ users there?

Comment: Ideally Server should be serving only target application and nothing else. If you install Jmeter on server then server will not perform to its full and thus you wont get correct capacity of server. practically you should use separate load generator than actual target server. If you need to generate heavy load, use cloud tools or more load generators but not server.

Comment: Okay , Can you please list here good cloud tools which I can use to do high level load testing?

Comment: blazemeter,neotys,blitz,RedLine13. drawback is good ones are never free

Comment: please accept the question edit changes or add those tags so that you might get good replies with new tools from performance people